# Launch subprocess in Ruby and continue execution of script

Tags: ruby, windows, shell, command-line, subprocess

I want to launch a subprocess in Ruby, concretely an external .exe file (I'm working in Windows environment). I don't want to block the Ruby script, so I want to return to the next line of the script while the subprocess is running. The Ruby script can even finish before the subprocess is done.

Is there any way to do it? I've tried exec(), fork(), spawn(), system()... but cannot make it work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Thread](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Thread.html):

`Thread.new { <your logic here> }`

There are a bunch of helper methods defined on `Thread` which will allow you to monitor and manipulate the thread.